# Не тематические или не тематичные?

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какое выражение следует использовать, если я хочу сказать, что публикуемая информация лежит за пределами допустимых тем сайта?

1. «Данная информация вне тематики сайта.»
2. «Данная информация не тематичная для сайта.»
3. «Данная информация не тематическая для сайта.»
4. Что–то другое.

Если какое–то выражение является недопустимым, то почему? Пожалуйста, если вы знаете более верное выражение, предложите его.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Прилагательное от "тематика/тема" - тематический. Тематичный - на молодежном жаргоне "предмет выского качества".

Лучше написать проще: Данная информация не соответствует тематике сайта.

Answer (score 2):

Первое выражение приемлемо; перед "вне" полезно добавить глагол (находится, лежит) или тире.

Во втором выражении лучше употребить краткую форму прилагательного ("не тематична" ~ не соответствует тематике сайта, не имеет к ней прямого отношения). Этот вариант имеет разговорный оттенок.

Третье выражение не совсем точно: понятие "тематический" абсолютно и указывает на принадлежность группы материалов названной общей теме (напр.: "у нас тематический сайт/вечер/сборник, посвящённый путешествиям"), поэтому прямое отрицание понятия "тематический" может характеризовать только всю группу материалов (это не тематическая подборка материалов, у сайта нет общей темы и т. п.), а не отдельный материал в сопоставлении с общей темой.